# Double (IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit) binary representation

Tags: java, floating-point, double, precision, floating-accuracy

I want to convert a Java double (IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit) to it's binary representation, modify the 21 least significant bits to embed some metadata into the double, convert it back to a double, and maintain 6 decimal places of precision.

Constraint: The double values I will be dealing with will always be in the range of [-180, 180].

Example:

```
Double value: -145.88160204733163

IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit binary:

1100 0000 0110 0010 0011 1100 0011 0110 0001 0101 0111 1111 0010 1100 0000 1000

IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit binary with 21 least significant bits modified:

1100 0000 0110 0010 0011 1100 0011 0110 0001 0101 0110 0010 1001 1000 0110 0101

Double value with 21 least significant bits modified:
-145.88160199410336
```

I understand 1 bit needs to be maintained for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 7 bits in the mantissa for the whole number between -180 and 180. Since I need to maintain 6 decimal places of precision, I thought an additional 24 bits for the significant figures would be sufficient to maintain 6 decimal places of precision (since 3.32 bits are required per digit, my understanding here might be incorrect) so I could use the 21 least significant bits to embed the metadata.

I'd like to know where I'm misunderstanding how 64-bit doubles are represented in binary and if there's any other way to modify the bits of a double without losing the required precision.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your computations are basically correct.  The mantissa is 52 bits, so chopping off 21 leaves 31, or about 9 digits.  You have clearly kept 8 digits of precision (145.88160).  Remember that "6 decimal digits" does not mean "6 places after the decimal point".  It starts from the first significant digit.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Your "before" and "after" numbers are the same, to 7 decimal places.  With your strategy, you could either increase the number slightly or decrease it slightly, and when you do that, there's always a chance that it will cross over a multiple of 0.000001.  So there's always a possibility that the  first six decimal places printed will differ (as has happened here), but the difference between the "before" and "after" numbers will always be far less than 0.000001.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you explain why I'm getting 8 digits of precision instead of 9 if I'm maintaining 31 bits of the 52 bits of the mantissa? How many bits in the mantissa would I need to keep to achieve 9 digits of precision? I'm seeing the above behavior even while maintaining 42 bits of the mantissa. For example, 134.82916000001586 becomes 134.82915999999622 even when only modifying the 10 least significant bits of the mantissa.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The before and after are the same to only 5 decimal places, I need it to be the same to 6 decimal places. Can you elaborate on why there's always a possibility that the first six decimal places will differ? My understanding is that maintaining the 31 most significant bits of the mantissa should result in 9 digits of precision being maintained. Why is that not the case? I'm seeing the above behavior even when maintaining 42 bits of the mantissa.

Comment: With rounding, you have 9 digits (145.881602).  You have to consider rounding when you're thinking about this.  Remember that all the talk about "decimal digits" is strictly for human interpretation of the data.  The computer works in binary, and it has 31 bits.

Comment: The before and after in your example are both `-145.8816020` to 7 decimal places.  Your statement - that they are the same to only 5 decimal places - is false.

Comment: As I explained earlier, changing the least significant 21 bits can increase or decrease the number very slightly, so that it crosses a multiple of 0.0000001.  In other words, it can change any of the first 7 places of the decimal expansion of the number; and there's absolutely nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @CoderGuy Does "maintain 6 decimal places of precision" mean you want to maintain 6 _significant_ places of precision or sddd.dddddd digits or what?  Consider the values 123.456 and 123.456e-10.

Comment: @CoderGuy Is it OK to "modify **more than** the 21 least significant bits to embed **a specified 21-bit** metadata into the double, convert it back to a double, and maintain 6 decimal places of precision"?  Example make x a 1 in 1100 0000 0110 0010 0011 1100 0011 0110 0001 0101 x110 0010 1001 1000 0110 0101.

Comment: @CoderGuy IOWs, take your value and form the mid-point in decimal form sddd.dddddd5 and adjust that value's lower 21 bits. Taking the mid-point reduces the chance of your payload affecting the sddd.dddddd decimal value.  I _think_ it may work for all `double x` where `|x| < 256`, yet have not done the analysis.  Knowing _why_ you want to do this would help too.  Does it need to be hard to _detect_ that the value changed?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I need to maintain 9 significant digits of precision. The reason I want to do this is that I am dealing with latitude/longitude values. For real world scenarios, only 9 significant digits of precision are required (8 significant digits for latitude and 9 significant digits for longitude), anything after those 8/9 digits doesn't make a difference in the accuracy of the latitude/longitude. I want to embed the metadata in the least significant bits to be able to distinguish the source of the latitude, ie. GPS, IP, etc.

Comment: Taking the value and forming the mid-point in decimal form: sddd.dddddd555555555 has seemed to get rid of the precision loss and actually allows me to use the 24 least significant bits to embed the metadata. Can you please explain why this works?

Comment: @CoderGuy To be clear we are on the same page: 1.23456789e-100 has 9 significant decimal digits of precision, right? and 000.000123 has only 3.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For my use-case, 1.23456789e-10 is just 000.000000, so I would need to maintain that and would be okay to lose the 123456789

Comment: @CoderGuy So it is not _significant_ decimal digits that need to be maintained, but a fixed point one of sddd.ddddddxx...xx.  I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When OP code changes the 21 least significant bits of the IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit value, the result is a value greater or less than the original.  Sometimes that change, even if only a change of 1 least significant bit in `Double` is enough to change the output when printed to 6 fractional decimal places.

---

Consider a decimal value ddd.dddddd5, where `d` are digits 0-9.  We have a value half-way between two ddd.dddddd values.  That value in rarely encodable *exactly* as a `Double`<sup>*1</sup>. A nearby `Double` is used, which when printed with 6 decimal places rounds to nearest 0.000001.  Output is ddd.dddddd or 0.000001 more depending on if the that nearest `Double` was a tad more or less than ddd.dddddd5.

If it prints as ddd.dddddd and the payload is more than the original 21 bits - even just 1 least significant bit more, the value prints 0.000001 more.  Like-wise, if it prints as ddd.dddddd + 0.000001 and the payload is less, it prints as ddd.dddddd.

To achieve OP's goal, we could round values to the nearest 0.000001 to get them away from the ddd.dddddd5 boundaries. Then we can successfully replace the least 21-bits as OP has described and reasoned.

Rounding is tricky as many rounding techniques incorrectly handle the edge conditions such as poor `round(x*1000000.0)/1000000.0`.  The problem here is `x * 1000000.0` does not always form an *exact* product - which is critical for edge cases.

I am not well versed in java, yet printing to 6 decimal fraction places and converting back to `Double` could do the trick.

---

Note that this answers differs from my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809242/double-ieee754-double-precision-64-bit-binary-representation?noredirect=1#comment130360869_73809242).  In that case I was focused on not changing the `d` digits of the value ddd.ddddddxxxxxx if printed out to many decimal places.  As I see it now, OP's want the same output when printed to 6 fractional decimal places.

<sup>*1</sup> All `Double`, when expressed *exactly* are have a decimal fraction of 0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, ....  Not 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, ...

Comment: To clarify, I want to 'not change the d digits of the value ddd.ddddddxxxxxx if printed out to all decimal places'. When I tried setting sddd.dddddd5, that resulted in the d digits changing, but when I used sddd.dddddd555555555 and then replaced the least significant bits, the d digits did not change

Comment: @CoderGuy Consider rounding the value to the nearest ddd.dddddd25 or ddd.dddddd75 to get it both far away from the nearest ddd.dddddd5 and ddd.dddddd0.